# Setting priors in rhierBinLogit function from basyem package

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical

I checked the sample code from the appendix of bayesian stat and marketing the sample code used default prior which is

```
nu = nvar + 3
V = nu * diag(nvar)
Deltabar = matrix(rep(0, nz * nvar), ncol = nvar)
ADelta = 0.01 * diag(nz)
```

I just want to try a different prior setting and see how is look like so I change the deltabar to be

```
Deltabar = matrix(rep(10, nz * nvar), ncol = nvar)
```

Based on my understanding that set the prior believe of the deltabar to start from 10 so the MCMC of delta should begin in the value of 10 (please correct me if I am wrong).

However, I get same trace plot as default prior.